# get object value by unknown key name in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var json ={
    "my_location": {
        "city": "city",
        "title": "my title",
        "complete_address": "my complete address",
        "geo": {
            "lat": 1.11111111,
            "lng": 1.22222222
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get by a string key name like this

```
var key_name="my_location.geo.lat"
```

please help me how i can get the value by usig this key_name in javascript

Comment: Provide a way you tried.

Comment: json+key_name and

 json.{(key_name)}

json[key_name]

but I am not successfull

Comment: You can get `lat` data by this syntax: `json['my_location']['geo']['lat]`

Comment: This is usually called "object graph navigation", and I am 100% certain there are multiple duplicate questions but I can't find them. The language (JavaScript) does not provide a way to do this, but it's not difficult to implement if you don't need to do anything fancy.

Comment: no I need by parsing that string because we will be using this for mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const getPropValue = (object, path = '') =>
path.split('.')
    .reduce((o, x) => o == undefined ? o : o[x]
    , object)
```

test with:

```
getPropValue(json, "my_location.geo.lat")
```